# set a cookie domain in Scoop of 3 in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I have a problem with the cookie domain I am using in **.mydomain.net** and I would like to have it in a scoop of 3 so it would be **.app.mydomain.net** 
So I have this:

```
    // Save siteminder cookie from a login succes and redirect to target application url
            log.debug("Certificate type: "+ s_certificateType );
            log.debug("Application Authentication Level: "+ s_authLevel );
            if ( s_certificateType.length() == 0 || s_certificateType.equals ("HARD") || ( s_certificateType.equals ("SOFT") && ( s_authLevel.equals("1") || s_authLevel.equals("2") ) ) ) {
                Cookie c_cookie = new Cookie ("SSOHUBSESSION", s_sessionToken );
                c_cookie.setDomain(application.getInitParameter("domain"));
                response.addCookie ( c_cookie );                
                log.debug("REDIRECT: "+ s_returnurl );
                                        session.invalidate();
                Cookie[] a_cookies = request.getCookies();
                if (a_cookies != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < a_cookies.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (a_cookies[i].getName().equals("SSOHUBFED_OLD_SESSION") ) {
                            log.debug("Update the SSOHUBFED_OLD_SESSION with the new Session. ");
                            c_cookie = new Cookie("SSOHUBFED_OLD_SESSION", s_sessionToken);
                            c_cookie.setDomain(application.getInitParameter("domain"));
                            //c_cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                            c_cookie.setValue(s_sessionToken);
                            response.addCookie(c_cookie);
                        }
                    }

                }


                response.sendRedirect(s_returnurl);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Here I was thinking to just add in the end response.addCookie(".app."+c_cookie);
I don't know maybe there is a way to get direcly the scoop of 3 or something!!!
Does anyone have an idea of how I can Do that ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do in the code, but in SiteMinder (aka CA SSO) the cookie domain scope is defined in the Agent Configuration Object. Also there will be a request header called SM_SDOMAIN or SMSDOMAIN (underscore may or may not be present, also depends on ACO settings) that contains the exact cookie domain that SiteMinder is using, e.g.

```
String smcookiedomain = request.getHeader("SM_SDOMAIN");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Well yes that excatly what i want to do. I know how to do it using the Agent (It's in the ACO side).
Now i am using SAML and i had to change the Pom.XML to fix the problem but I have a new cookie that i don't understand where its from ? It's a page called SAML2SSO that send an other cookie and i don't know how to fix that?

Comment: What cookie is it?